# Special character encoding french cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, encoding, character-encoding

I have this code to put my string french

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Envoie');?>
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        <?php echo __('Imaa Envoie'); ?>
    </legend>
    <textarea name="data[code]" cols="30" rows="12"  ></textarea>


</fieldset>


<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));?>
```

In my controller i have this code

```
$string=explode("extract", $this->request->data["code"]);
        $sum="";               
         $id=trim($string[0]);
         $sum=$sum.$id;
         $sum=str_replace ( "nice", 'hire', $sum);
        $this->set("sum",$sum);
```

In my view i have this

```
<?=$sum ?>
```

String in is : `157m² de superficie, 2ème étage, 2 Salons, 2 ch., 2 SDB, Séjour, Cuisine, Buanderie, …`

String out is : `157mÂ² de superficie, 2Ã¨me Ã©tage, 2 Salons, 2 ch., 2 SDB, SÃ©jour, Cuisine, Buanderie,â�¦`

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this must be the most confusing code I've seen in a long time and I don't have a clue what you're trying to do.

Still what should bother you is that you're using no cakePHP code other than the first line and the last line, so your problem can not be cake related.

What it is, is that unicode characters can not be handled like you do with indices (ie. `$ssssss[0]` because è or é etc are represented with two bytes and you're only are getting the first byte, corrupting the stream afterwards.

Comment: I use this code in a personal application and it is a way to secure my little algorithm how i can get a solution for my problem

Comment: The solution is already mentioned in my post: You need to understand how multibyte strings are handled in php. Noone can give you a better answer without knowing what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

in your layout view file head section add this:

```
if (!isset($l10n)
     $l10n=new L10n;
$catalog=$l10n->catalog('fra') ; // your locale
echo $this->Html->charset($catalog['charset']) ;
```

it will find out and set the charset of the locale (which you may don't know) automatically.